# Prove that ABCD is a rectangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

From the 2018 Moroccan Mathematics Olympiad:

> Let $E,F, $ and $B$ three distinct points on the plane such that: $B \in [EF]$. Let the semi-circles $(C_1), (C_2)$ and $(C_3)$ with diameters, respectively, $[EF], [EB]$ and $[BF]$ and which lie on the same semi-plane defined by [EF]. The common tangent to $(C_2)$ and $(C_3)$, through B, cuts $(C_1)$ in $D$. The other tangent to $(C_2)$ and $(C_3)$, cuts them respectively at $A$ and $C$.

> Prove that $ABCD$ is a rectangle.

**My Approach**:

Let $O=(AC) \cap (BD)$.

We have: $Pow_{(C_2)}(O)=OB^2=OA^2$, and $Pow_{(C_3)}(O)=OB^2=OC^2$.
Thus $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle ($\angle B=90$), and $O$ is the midpoint of $[AC]$. Now, we only have to show $O$ is the midpoint of $[BD]$, but I wasn't able to do that.

(Here: $Pow_{\omega}(P)$ is the power of point $P$ with respect to the circle $\omega$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A':=ED\cap C_2\neq E, C':=FD\cap C_3\neq F$. In virtue of [Thales's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), we infer $$\angle EA'B=90^\circ\implies \angle BA'D=90^\circ, \quad \angle EDF=\angle A'DC'=90^\circ, \quad \angle BC'F=90^\circ\implies \angle DC'B=90^\circ$$

[image]

Hence, $BC'DA'$ is a rectangle, so we only need to prove that $A'C'$ is tangent to both $C_2,C_3$.

> This, however, follows from similarity considerations, i.e. $$\angle A'C'B=\angle A'DB=\angle EDB=\angle DFB=\angle C'FB\implies A'C'\text{ is tangent to }C_3$$
> (where we have used that $\triangle EBD\sim \triangle FBD$). A similar reasoning applies to $\angle BA'C'=\angle BEA'$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have shown that $\angle{ABC} = 90°$, what remains to prove is that $\angle{ADC} = 90°$. Let $H_A$ and $H_C$ be the feet of the perpendiculars dropped from $A$ and $C$ to $EF$, respectively. As you have proved, we have $AO = OC$, which implies $H_{A}B = BH_C$ since $OB \perp EF$. We can verify that $\triangle{EAB} \sim \triangle{BCF}$ by angle chasing. Therefore, $$\frac{EH_A}{H_{A}B} = \frac{BH_C}{H_{C}F}.$$

Since $$\frac{EB}{BF} = \frac{EH_A + H_{A}B}{BH_C + H_{C}F} = \frac{EH_A + BH_C}{H_{A}B + H_{C}F},$$ we can conclude that $B$ divides the segment $[EF]$ in the same ratio as $A$ in $[EB]$ and $C$ in $[BF]$. This is sufficient to prove the desired result. I would consider a homothety centered at $E$ sending $B$ to $F$ to complete the proof. However, there are various ways to express the same idea and I think it is more constructive to leave it to you to write the finale of the proof.